# Conjur in docker error

Tags: cyber-ark

```
root@272c02832f2c:~/conjur/tutorials/secrets# conjur policy load --as-group security_admin --namespace $NAMESPACE policy.yml
error: Unknown option --as-group

NAME
   load - Load a policy

SYNOPSIS
   conjur [global options] policy load [command options] POLICY FILENAME

COMMAND OPTIONS
   --[no-]delete  - Allow explicit deletion statements in the policy.
   --[no-]replace - Fully replace the existing policy, deleting any data that
                    is not declared in the new policy.
root@272c02832f2c:~/conjur/tutorials/secrets#
```

How do i resolve the error? Can anybody help me on this issue.

Comment: Any update on my issue?

Answer (score 1):

This command will work:

```
$ conjur policy load <namespace> policy.yml
```

You don’t need to worry about the `--as-group security_admin` bit.  The namespace is declared before the policy file rather than as a separate argument.